# Can't connect to CRM Online from Reporting Services Manager

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm

I created report in VIsual Studio that connected to CRM Onlyne using FetchXML and it works good from visual studio. Now i'm trying to deploy it on Reporting Services server. I faced with issue that i can't create DataSource from Reporting Services Manager. Do you have any ideas how to fix it. See screenshot with error https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/35df977a-c903-4fec-89f6-2f0c6b7e5a10/cant-connect-to-crm-online-from-reporting-services-manager?forum=crmdevelopment

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot connect to remote MS Dynamics CRM Fetch XML datasource from SSRS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25430201/cannot-connect-to-remote-ms-dynamics-crm-fetch-xml-datasource-from-ssrs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Donal. There is answer for my question. It was surprise for me that i can't use FetchXML datasource for connect to CRM online but i found workeround. I implemented a Data Processing Extension for Reporting Servies for request data from CRM Online. For a basis i get following article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22946/Implementing-a-Data-Processing-Extension